# Apple Submission has reached the timeout limit while using Expo and EAS build for an IOS application

Tags: expo, app-store-connect, eas, app-store-connect-api

When I use eas build to upload my app to appstoreconnect so I can test on TestFlight the build is completed correctly, but it fails on the upload to apple and reaches the timeout limit. This is an issue that has started in the past few days after a month or so of successful builds without any issue. Has anyone else had this issue, and if so how did you resolve it

Starting the submit process
2

Downloading archive
3

Preparing artifact
4

Verifying archive
5

Creating ascApiJsonKey.json file with ASC credentials
6

Submitting iOS app to TestFlight...
7

Submitting the app with fastlane pilot
8

---

9

--- Step: pilot ---
10

---

11

Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
12

Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 6472619688)...
13

Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
14

This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
15

Fastlane pilot failed Submission has reached the timeout limit. Try again.

16

Failed to submit the app Fastlane pilot failed Submission has reached the timeout limit. Try again.

I have tried multiple times to re initiate the process but all submissions have failed... leading to unnecessary build charges from expo